# Flash reduce line with programmatically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stroke

I have some flash animation files with stroke 4. Its a series of animation all characters have same stroke.

But now need to reduce the line stroke from 4 to 1.5.

My doubt is is there any programmatic way to reduce all the stroke values in that particular scene?

Comment: AFAIK, only sprites created dynamically can have strokes which can be controlled dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's called line [thickness](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/GraphicsStroke.html#thickness). And you can use the [lineStyle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineStyle%28%29) to set it.

For eg, To set a line width of 10 :

```
mc.graphics.lineStyle(10, 0xFFD700, 1, false, LineScaleMode.VERTICAL,
                          CapsStyle.NONE, JointStyle.MITER, 10);
```

Comment: I think, he is saying about objects drawn on Flash Timeline (and not dynamically created sprites).

Comment: Non dynamically created object is actually a [Shape](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Shape.html) and is accessible from code by iterating through all the children on stage.  It also has the graphics property.

Comment: But I have tried it and there is no change. Please can you provide complete working piece of code. Thanks.